# How to resolve the SSLHandshake Exception?

Tags: java, http, ssl-certificate

How to resolve "SSLHANDSHAKE Exception" and also how to maintain "Cookies" in httpClient post method. I have pass Some session parameter "nameValuePair" and cookies into http client post method.
After posting all parameter in "httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod)" it doesn't go for next "postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();" after its show some exception.

```
try {
            initialState = new HttpState();
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(25000);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(25000));
            httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("127.0.0.1",8888);
         // Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
         // systemProperties.put("proxySet", "true");
         // systemProperties.put("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
         // systemProperties.put("http.proxyPort", 8888);
            try {
                httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
                //   httpClient.getState().setProxyCredentials(null, null, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(null, null));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            //httpClient.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

            cookies = httpClient.getState().getCookies();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            postMethod = new PostMethod(pageUrl);
            postMethod.addParameter("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("KeepAlive", "true");
            postMethod.setFollowRedirects(FollowRedirect);
            postMethod.setDoAuthentication(DoAuthentication);

            if (referer != null) {
                postMethod.addRequestHeader("referer", referer);
            }
            if (cookieArr != null) {
                cookies = new Cookie[cookieArr.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
                    cookies[i] = new Cookie(".linkedin.com", cookieArr[i][0], cookieArr[i][0], "/", null, true);
                }
            }
            initialState.addCookies(cookies);
            int postDataLength = postData.length;
            NameValuePair[] nameValuePair = new NameValuePair[postDataLength];
            for (int i = 0; i < postDataLength; i++) {
                nameValuePair[i] = new NameValuePair(postData[i][0], postData[i][1]);
            }

            postMethod.addParameters(nameValuePair);
            httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
            cookies = httpClient.getState().getCookies();
            pageSouce = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            postMethod.releaseConnection();
        }
```

But it shows the following exception when run:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
 find valid certification path to requested target

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
 unable to find valid certification path to requested target

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the server does not have a valid certificate. Probably the Root-CA of the server is not contained in your java cacert.

Maybe this will help: http://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification

Comment: In posting method how to maintain cookies.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.